# Can you insert the results of a dynamic sql call into a SQL Server 2005 table variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there anyway to do this in SQL Server 2005?

```
declare @tv_tablelist table (recnum int identity(1,1) primary key, newvar varchar(500))

declare @mysql nvarchar(4000)

set @mysql = 'insert into @tv_tablelist(newvar) values (''test test test'')'


      Exec sp_executesql @mysql,      
            N'@tv_tablelist table (recnum int identity(1,1) primary key, newvar varchar(500)) OUTPUT',      
      @tv_tablelist OUTPUT  

select * from @tv_tablelist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you require, have you tries something like

```
declare @tv_tablelist table (recnum int identity(1,1) primary key, newvar varchar(500)) 

declare @mysql nvarchar(4000) 

set @mysql = 'SELECT ''test test test''' 

INSERT INTO @tv_tablelist Exec sp_executesql @mysql

select * from @tv_tablelist
```

Output

```
recnum      newvar
----------- --------------
1           test test test
```